# How to prevent my silver jewelry from turning black?

Tags: cleaning, jewelry

I have silver jewelry which is expensive and I am worried because it is turning black I put it in separate box from other jewelry.

1. How to prevent it from turning black?
2. how to clean the black stain that have already appear on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your silver jewelry by putting them in talcum powder. You will take a small amount of powder in tissue paper and put the jewelry in it. It saves silver jewelry from turning black.

To remove black stains from jewelry, you can wash the jewelry with soap and apply toothpaste with a tooth brush if your silver jewelry is genuine, stains can be removed.

Comment: Toothpaste contains abrasive particles that can scratch and dull the surface. Please be careful when trying this.

Answer (score 1):

please follow these steps to prevent from turning black..

1  Keep it clean. After wearing your sterling silver jewelry, clean it with a dry soft cloth, or polishing cloth, before storing it away.
2  Keep it safe. Store your clean dry sterling silver jewelry in a dry airtight container.

Comment: Air tight will help some as it is traces of hydrogen sulfide in the air that produce black silver sulfide. Cleaning with a fine abrasive like tooth powder/paste is probably the most practical cleaning method.

Answer (score 0):

This contains two questions, and I will only answer the second one.

How to clean silver as a lifehack: Get a bowl of warm water. Add some silver foil (which is not actually silver, you know) and some baking powder, then your silver, and stir it around a bit. This makes a weak battery and the black stuff comes off. If it's being difficult help it with an old toothbrush. It will come out like new.

Answer (score 0):

Take one spoon safaidi powder and mix it in  one jugg water,put your jewelry in it for over night.next day your jewelry will as shine as you purchased newly.